# Как подключить шрифт к html странице, которая загружена в WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Есть HTML код, сгенерированный программно и загруженный в WebView.
В этом коде используется шрифт, которого нет на устройстве.

Как подключить шрифт например через Assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете подсунуть свои стили

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf")
}
body {
    font-family: MyFont;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
```

предварительно загрузив asset'ы:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                            WebClient.getStyledFont(someText),
                            "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, "about:blank");
```

и добавив их в код страницы

```
public static String getStyledFont(String html) {
    boolean addBodyStart = !html.toLowerCase().contains("<body>");
    boolean addBodyEnd = !html.toLowerCase().contains("</body");
    return "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: CustomFont;" +
            "src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Brandon_reg.otf\")}" +
            "body {font-family: CustomFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style>" +
            (addBodyStart ? "<body>" : "") + html + (addBodyEnd ? "</body>" : "");
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)